# Как-то странно работает os.path.abspath()

Tags: python, path, ос

```
import os
txt = "\\folder\\file.txt"
abs = os.path.abspath(txt)
print(abs)
```

И выводит C:\folder\file.txt, хотя файл находится на диске D

Comment: *Люблю*, когда вопросы задаются с наездом на язык/платформу/метод основной библиотеки. "Это не я не понимаю, как это работает! Оно просто работает неправильно"

Comment: Данный метод не носится по всей Вашей файловой системе (и по всем подключённым дискам) в поисках указанного файла. Он просто берет относительный путь и достраивает его до абсолютного

Comment: А где сказано, что файл находится на диске Д?

Answer (score 0):

import os

txt = "D:\folder\file.txt"
file = os.path.abspath(txt)
print(file)

Comment: Точно? Проверено?

Comment: abs кстати зарезервированное слово и лучше его как имя переменной не использовать.

Comment: 1) судя по его вопросу надо чтобы выводило D:\folder\file.txt + к этому сам файл там находится. Проверено
2) согласен

Comment: Так тогда можно просто написать `print("D:\folder\file.txt"`. Я вот совсем не уверен, в чем именно заключается вопрос.

Comment: СОГЛАСЕН С ТОБОЙ!